# Why does Visual Studio 2019 default to C++14 not C++17?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I noticed today that even with up to date VS2019, by default a new C++ project uses C++14:

[image]

This suggests to me there is a good reason not to use C++17... does anyone know why '14 remains the default?

Comment: Make sure to add the C++ tag to such questions. More users will see the post that way.

Comment: Maybe because there are things in C++17 that would silently break a C++14 program, and MS wants to make sure that out-of-the-box VS 2019 works for those legacy programs?

Comment: MS is veeery risk averse. For instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-cplusplus?view=msvc-160 - So I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie 'maybe' as in there are such things, or their might be such things?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Haven't gone through the entire spec, but I would try [this page](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html).